# Is it possible to have user-defined Struct as a _KeyType in a Mapping in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, struct, mapping

I'm trying to define a Struct type, and use it as a _keytype for a mapping.

```
contract TestContract
{
    struct Structure {
        bytes32 structure_name;
    }

    mapping (Structure => address) public test_mapping;
}
```

Using [Solidity real time compiler](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=0.3.6) I get the following error message:

> Error: Expected elementary type name for mapping key type

However, according to [Solidity's documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#mappings), every data type except for 'mapping' can be used for _keytype:

> Mapping types are declared as mapping _KeyType => _ValueType, where _KeyType can be almost any type except for a mapping and _ValueType can actually be any type, including mappings.

Did I understand the documentation wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, a mapping with a struct as the key isn't supported.

It's a known issue:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/599